# How to hide irrelevant vobs in clearcase dynamic views (in windows)?

Tags: clearcase, vob, config-spec

1st post here so I hope I'm not breaking any rules.

To the point:
I work on multiple projects and therefore may have multiple vobs mounted at any given time that are unrelated to the view that i want to work on at the moment. This causes each view that I have created to show each and every mounted vob. This is obviously not desirable behavior, is there a way i can use the config spec for a dynamic view to only show the vobs related to that view?

I have tried adding the following in the config spec:

```
element /irrelevant_vob/ -none
```

or

```
element /irrelevant_vob/... -none
```

or

```
 element irrelevant_vob -none
```

I also tried something like this:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element /relevant_vob1/...//main/LATEST
element /relevant_vob2/...//main/LATEST
element * -none
```

but in all the above cases, the irrelevant_vob is still in the folder tree but empty.
What I would like to do is to completely hide the irrelevant vobs from the view.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention in this [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146877), this is not possible with dynamic views:

> There is no option currently available.
>   Change request (RFE) RATLC00607238, was submitted to add a feature for excluding VOBs from a dynamic view.
>
> The decision was made by Product Management to exclude the resolution of this enhancement from future upgrades and releases due to the significant architectural changes required to implement the solution.

One workaround I like, on Windows, is to assign a drive letter to a view/avob (but in your case, you have several relevant vobs).
Another is to create symlinks (for unix, could work on Windows 7 though) to the relevant vobs of a given view, with those symlinks made in a special folder (made to list said symlinks).
But that means ClearCase operations (checkout/checkins) may not work properly with such indirections.

Comment: I see. Your idea with the symlinks is quite interesting but as you pointed out, might have problems with checkins/-outs.
Oh well... I think I'll have to live with the extra empty vobs on the views. Thanks anyway :)